# Flink's "TypeSerializerOutputFormat" writes weird binary data together

Tags: apache-flink

I use Flink to generate array data to be used by the other applications. (I don't need any metainfo for the array)
I compared the binary data and text data generated by Flink, and found an weird data in binary data.

```
val bin_output_format = new TypeSerializerOutputFormat[(Long, Long)]  
bin_output_format.setWriteMode (WriteMode.OVERWRITE)
bin_output_format.setOutputFilePath(new Path (s"${outDir}/NAME_Binary")) 

tuple_pair_list.map { tuple => tuple._1 + "\t" + tuple._2}.writeAsText(s"${outDir}/NAME_TXT", WriteMode.OVERWRITE)                        
tuple_pair_list.output (bin_output_format)
```

1. How can I remove the metainfo appended at the end of the binary file?
   (it looks like the number of entries)
2. Why there is some wrong data in it? Can I remove them? You can see the difference between two in the following figure.( two (127, -1 , -1) and one NULLs)

[image] [image]

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flink's `TypeSerializerOutputFormat` is designed to work together with the `TypeSerializerInputFormat` and allow for parallelized file scans. Flink uses it's internal serializers for binary encoding. Some of these serializers are based on external libraries such as Avro and Kryo. The encoding might change whenever the internal implementation of Flink's serializers (or the used libraries) changes. Moreover, the output format aligns data at fixed block boundaries and uses padding if a record would span a boundary.

Hence, the output of the `TypeSerializerOutputFormat` is not meant to be consumed by other tools or readers. I would implement a custom `OutputFormat`.

Comment: To extend Fabian's answer, Flink's `TypeSerializer*Format` is comparable to Hadoop's SequenceFile format.

Maybe its also easier for you to just use Flink's TypeSerializerInputFormat in the custom application as well (in a non parallel way).

Another option are formats like Avro, Parquet etc.

Comment: Got it!. Thanks for your prompt response :D It seems I need to customize 'BinaryOutputFormat' class for my own purpose

Comment: Please be aware that the block boundary logic to support parallel scans is implemented in `BinaryOutputFormat`. So, the resulting files might have internal padding bytes as well. If you want to write a binary file for "simple" sequential scans, you should extend the `FileOutputFormat`.